# Can we install plugins in the browser(Chrome or FireFox) automatically through JavaScript

Tags: javascript, plugins

I Just want to know if we can install a plugins automatically on the client system through JavaScript without asking the user to install it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. That'd be horrifying, don't you think?

Answer (score 2):

No. It's a browser's security-feature that requires user-interaction. You could do very evil things, if installing without asking would be possible!

Comment: If not can you please suggest me how can i get list of all the installed plugins in Chrome. Actually I've installed a plugin in bot Chrome and Mozilla and able to find in Mozilla through JavaScript, But it is not showing in Chrome.

Comment: @AmishKumar: You should ask a new question for this.